# Python: select points that fall within two arbitrary curves

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation

I want to select the points that fall within two arbitrary curves, each defined by an array of points. Below is an example. In reality, the curves I have are not based on a functional form, they are arrays. How can I select only the points that fall within the red and blue curve, and say, color them a different color?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate arrays from gaussian
x = np.linspace(0.5, 3.5, 120)
y = np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.8, 2.)))
yy = .5*np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.4, 2.)))

# generate random data points
data_x = 4*np.random.rand(1000)
data_y = np.random.rand(1000)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, c='k', s=.1)
ax.scatter(x,y, s=3)
ax.scatter(x,yy, c='r', s=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Interpolate those curves (scipy; some model-decision needed on the kind of interpolation; probably something monotonic) and then boolean-logic (which is part of mpl's fill_between API already -> arg where). Theoretical remark: you will *always* need some kind of a-priori assumptions / regularizations with incomplete cuves like that; in this case part of the interpolation.

Comment: In your actual data, are the x values the same for the two curves and the data? ... is (x0, x1, x2, x3, ...) the same for all three data sets?

Comment: Yes, I figured I need to interpolate. Do you have code for what you describing?

Comment: No, x data is not the same.

Comment: What @sascha said: Use one of the [Numpy Polynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.polynomials.html) functions/classes/methods (or SciPy as well) to *create* polynomials for the two curves and use them as the upper and lower bounds: iterate over the *data*; evaluate the curves at each datum's x-value; compare the y-values ; keep/discard.

Comment: I don't think creating polynomials will be good in this case, it needs to be some sort of interpolation of the curve points.

Comment: Iterate over the data; for each datum's x-value do a linear fit/interpolation for the nearest x-values in the curves; evaluate the fits at the datum's x-value; compare y-values; keep/discard.  Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a code writing service.  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: "evaluate the fits at the datum's x-value" what do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You may use `numpy.interp` to interpolate the points on the positions of the arrays that define the curves.

```
c1 = data_y > np.interp(data_x, x,yy)
c2 = data_y < np.interp(data_x, x,y)
```

Then set the color of the scatter as `c=(c1&c2)` and select a colormap of choice.

```
ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, c=(c1&c2), s=1, cmap="summer_r")
```

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate arrays from gaussian
x = np.linspace(0.5, 3.5, 120)
y = np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.8, 2.)))
yy = .5*np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.4, 2.)))

# generate random data points
data_x = 4*np.random.rand(1000)
data_y = np.random.rand(1000)

c1 = data_y > np.interp(data_x, x,yy)
c2 = data_y < np.interp(data_x, x,y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, c=(c1&c2), s=1, cmap="summer_r")
ax.scatter(x,y, s=3)
ax.scatter(x,yy, c='r', s=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. It implements numpy interpolating function, `np.interp()` as mentioned in the comments.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate arrays from gaussian
x = np.linspace(0, 5, 120)

# 2 sets of y's for given x
# these can be any reasonable array of numbers
y = np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.8, 2.)))
yy = .5*np.exp(-np.power(x - 2, 2.) / (2 * np.power(.4, 2.)))

fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(9, 7)
ax = plt.axes()

# plot curves using interpolating data
numpnts = 60
xs = np.linspace(0, 4, numpnts)
ys1 = np.interp(xs, x, y)
ys2 = np.interp(xs, x, yy)

#ax.scatter(xs,ys1, c='b', s=8)  # blue
#ax.scatter(xs,ys2, c='r', s=8)  # red

# for the reference curves
# better use plot than scatter
ax.plot(xs, ys1, 'b^-', xs, ys2, 'ro-', markersize=4, linewidth=0.3)  # blue

# this function uses the interpolated data just created
# and helps build color array for scatter plot
def in_btw(x, y):
    uppr = np.interp(x, xs, ys1)
    lowr = np.interp(x, xs, ys2)
    tf1 = lowr < y
    tf2 = y < uppr
    colr = 'c'
    if tf1 and tf2:
        colr = 'pink'
    return colr

# generate random data points
data_x = 4*np.random.rand(1200)
data_y = np.random.rand(1200)

clrs = []
for ix,ea in enumerate(data_x):
    #print (ea, in_btw(ea, data_y[ix]))
    ret = in_btw(ea, data_y[ix])
    clrs.append(ret)

# scatter plot of the data points with distinct colors
# color: pink if location is between the 2 curves, else, cyan
ax.scatter(data_x, data_y, c=clrs, s=4)

plt.show()
```

The resulting image:

[image]